# Set aspect ratio in PercentageRelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-percentrelativelayout

I want to set aspect ratio for my `FrameLayout` inside `PercentRelativeLayout` programmatically.

I already tried in `xml`, it's working:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="178%" //aspect ratio
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/liveTV_frame"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:keepScreenOn="true">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

But I need to set it programmatically.

How can I do that?

Comment: Without any reason , why people's are downvote this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PercentRelativeLayout layout = ...;
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams 
           = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.getPercentLayoutInfo().aspectRatio = ...; // float value
layout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But What is the float value ?. I need to set 178% as float.

Comment: You can see how that value is counted [in the sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/percent/src/android/support/percent/PercentLayoutHelper.java#L234).

Answer (score 0):

From @azizbekian Answer just i elaborate my answer,

Without using fractions, set float value of percentage :

```
 PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mFlPromoVideoContainer.getLayoutParams();
        PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
        info.widthPercent = 1f;
        info.aspectRatio = 1.78f;//178%
        mFlPromoVideoContainer.requestLayout();
```

You specify fractions in XML as so:

```
<item name="aspect_ratio" type="fraction">178%</item>
```

In Java,

```
 PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mFlPromoVideoContainer.getLayoutParams();
        PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
        info.widthPercent = 1f;
        info.aspectRatio = getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.aspect_ratio, 1, 1);
        mFlPromoVideoContainer.requestLayout();
```